# Stop inserting comments into function autocompletes Oracle Developer Tools in VS Code

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code

Here is an example of what happens:

I'm typing say - `SUM()`

If i accept the autocompletion it inserts:
`SUM(P_ /*[ DISTINCT | ALL ] EXPR*/)`

this infuriates me intensely because now I have to delete comments to maintain readability, making using intellisense slower than just typing it myself.

How can I disable this comment insertion?

Comment: I did not find a way to do so. Let's hope it becomes switchable on/off in newer versions.

Comment: It isn't possible to disable this, but I will make sure this is in the list for future enhancements.